# How to create a 2D string array to represent the calendar of a specific month, given the month and year?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, calendar

I want to create a 2D array that represents the calendar for a specific month.

```
public static String[][] calendar(String month, String year)
```

For example, this is the calendar for September 2019:

```
MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
 .   .   .   .   .   .   1
 2   3   4   5   6   7   8
 9   10  11  12  13  14  15
 16  17  18  19  20  21  22
 23  24  25  26  27  28  29
 30  .   .   .   .   .   .
```

The first row is always "MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN". Columns with no date need to be filled with a period. The number of rows can change depending on the number of days. There should not be an extra row with only period. So this can also happen:

```
MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN
 .   .   .   .   .   1   2
 3   4   5   6   7   8   9
 10  11  12  13  14  15  16
 17  18  19  20  21  22  23
 24  25  26  27  28  29  .
```

I have created some helper methods. These are not exactly the same as the ones in my code but the general purposes are the same:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(String year) {
  //return true if is leap year, false otherwise.
}

public static int numberOfDaysInMonth(String month, String year) {
  if(month.equals("JAN") || month.equals("MAR") || month.equals("MAY") || 
      month.equals("JUL") || month.equals("AUG") || month.equals("OCT") || 
          month.equals("DEC")
    return 31;
  else if(month.equals("APR") || month.equals("JUN") || month.equals("SEP") ||
      month.equals("NOV"))
    return 30;
  else if(isLeapYear(year) == true)
    return 29;
  else
    return 28;
}

public static int firstDayOfWeekInMonth(String month, String year) {
    /**returns the index of the first day of week in a specific month, MON = 0, TUE = 1, and so on. 
        For example, firstDayOfWeekInMonth("OCT", "2019") returns 1 because first day of month is Tuesday.
    */
```

My homework asks me to create my own code that can print out a calendar with that specific format, so I cannot use the API. No special leap year or difference between countries is considered.

If these are the codes that I created, how can I create a 2D array that represents the calendar of a month?

Comment: I would like to get first day of each month using the method firstDayOfWeekInMonth, which returns the index of first day of the specific month.

Comment: It is almost alwayas a *terrible, abysmal, and horrible* idea to try to write your own time and date systems. If you need time and date data, then you should *always* use an API that someone else has written, with *very* few exceptions. It is simply too difficult to handle all of what is required when writing your own system (e.g. every time a country decided to skip a day, leap years, multiple calendar systems, variations across geography). (1/2)

Comment: Luckily, Java has excellent APIs built in to deal with these things. Duckduckgo "Java time & date" for more information regarding the APIs that Java has. If you're not yet convinced that you should not even attempt to handle this yourself, this video is very worth watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY (2/2)

Comment: Here is enough to get started with the `java.time` api: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy");
  YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse(String.format("%s %s", month, year), formatter);
  LocalDate start = ym.atDay(1);
  DayOfWeek st = start.getDayOfWeek();
  LocalDate end = ym.atEndOfMonth();`

Comment: Note: you only invent your own time/date stuff ... when your homework assignemtn asks you to do that. In any other case, use the standard Java APIs.

Comment: @Goion The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Please don't recommend it, that's bad advice. The questioner needs the `LocalDate` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: My homework asks me to create my own code that can print out a calendar with that specific format, so I cannot use the API.   No special leap year or difference between countries is considered.